# Fetch Google plus contacts in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, google-plus

I have google login feature implemented in my Rails app and now the scenario is to fetch google plus contacts in my app.

There is one Google Plus gem available but i am not sure whether i can fullfill my requirements using that gem.

Whats the best possible solution to this.

Regards,
Karan

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Google APIs Ruby Client](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client) and do something like:

```
client = Google::APIClient.new
plus = client.discovered_api('plus')

# Code to authorize the client.
...

result = client.execute(plus.people.list,
  :collection => 'visible',
  :userId => 'me')
```

Where the code that you need to authorize the client depends on the flow that you are using to implement the login.

Answer (score 0):

I've encounter the same situation, nowhere was clear answer. 
What gem you are using for Google Authorization? If you are using omniauth-google-oauth2 here is the solution:

I've found post of a guy who encounter different problem AFTER part of application you are asking for was done, you may find it here - http://blog.baugues.com/google-calendar-api-oauth2-and-ruby-on-rails

Down to the code, this how you callback function in a controller (after logging in) should looks like:

```
 def create  #lets say it is session#new controller
omniauth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
authentication = Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid(omniauth['provider'], omniauth['uid'])
initial_session(omniauth) unless current_user
 client = Google::APIClient.new()
 client.authorization.access_token = omniauth["credentials"]["token"]
 plus = client.discovered_api('plus')
 contacts = client.execute(plus.people.list, :collection => 'visible',
                                           :userId => 'me')
 raise contacts.inspect.to_s
```