# Access Google Plus Contacts google-api-ruby-client and omniauth-google-oauth2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-api, omniauth, google-api-client

I want to get contact from Google Plus.
I am using

```
gem "omniauth"
gem "omniauth-google-oauth2"
```

for authentication and

```
gem "google-api-client"
```

for comunicate with google apis.

So far authentication is working fine and I got **access_token** after authentication.
Now problem is I couldn't find a way to get list of people in my circle (My Google Plus Contact).

Is there any way to do this.

Specifically I need to know is there any gem more like "fb_graph" for google?

I found this trick

```
https://plus.google.com/u/0/_/socialgraph/lookup/visible/o=%5Bnull%2Cnull%2C%22_UID_%22%5D&rt=j
```

Just need to put "UID" and you can get contacts in your circle but their name and ID only. But I need more information...

**WorkFlow**

```
client = Google::APIClient.new
client.authorization.client_id = GOOGLE_CONFIG[:app_id]
client.authorization.client_secret = GOOGLE_CONFIG[:app_secret]
client.authorization.access_token = token
plus = client.discovered_api('plus')
data = client.execute( plus.people.list, :collection => 'connected', :userId => 'me').data
```

In data I get this message

```
<Google::APIClient::Schema::Plus::V1::PeopleFeed:0x6569248 DATA:{"error"=>{"errors"=>[{"domain"=>"global", "reason"=>"insufficientPermissions", "message"=>"Insufficient Permission"}], "code"=>403, "message"=>"Insufficient Permission"}}>
```

I found similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16778450/fetch-google-plus-contacts-in-rails-app?answertab=active#tab-top) but solution is still needs to be find out.

Comment: Try changing the `scope` of your omniauth-google-oauth2 gem. You could also try using the new option `:skip_friends => false`.

Comment: @Ashitaka thanks for replying. I used your suggestion but no luck. I had updated my question(added some workflow). I got "token" after Authentication from Google by Google-Omniauth and want to use this specific token to access contacts...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I need to add **Scope** in devise initializers and then by auth token everything seems to be working perfectly.

```
scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"
```

OR Add this line

```
config.omniauth :google_oauth2, GOOGLE_CONFIG[:app_id], GOOGLE_CONFIG[:app_secret],{ access_type: "offline", approval_prompt: "force", scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile', name: 'google'}
```

Comment: Just a note: The README of omniauth-google-oauth2 states "Scopes starting with `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/` do not need that prefix specified."