# What is this Ruby data type?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-oauth

I'm trying to access the data returned by omniauth-google-oauth2 when trying to get the list of friends on Google Plus. As per this example: [Access Google Plus Contacts google-api-ruby-client and omniauth-google-oauth2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20804490/access-google-plus-contacts-google-api-ruby-client-and-omniauth-google-oauth2)

Below is what I receive. But I'm not sure how to access the data inside... How would I access "totalItems" and the "ID" of each item?

```
#<Google::APIClient::Schema::Plus::V1::PeopleFeed:0x3fe23371942c DATA:{"kind"=>"plus#peopleFeed", "etag"=>"\"L2Xbn8bDuSErT6QA3PEQiwYKQxM/mZ7BwKMAmnHq1YqeqfmoWNwqzeo\"", "title"=>"Google+ List of Connected People", "totalItems"=>1, "items"=>[{"kind"=>"plus#person", "etag"=>"\"L2Xbn8bDuSErT6QA3PEQiwYKQxM/MtyIlmmWQjDBCz3k5wZI9k7O4p8\"", "objectType"=>"person", "id"=>"118404349465393928176", "displayName"=>"Hélène Ponty", "url"=>"https://plus.google.com/118404349465393928176", "image"=>{"url"=>"https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-9w6_N_yJ5zc/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAeg/PnYBbkTFqYE/photo.jpg?sz=50"}}]}>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using `.methods` or `.instance_methods` to get the list of all accessible methods (for class and instance respectively):

```
your_object.methods

your_object.instance_methods
```